# How do i do a MySql Update query with join

Tags: mysql

I have a query that lists all bookings with a status of reminder e-mail of bookings 90 days foward

I would like to have a update query that change status 1 to 0
I have start with this update query without luck

This is the query thats give me the list i want to update

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ts_booking_bookings b
  JOIN ts_booking_bookings_slots s 
    ON b.id = s.booking_id 
 WHERE b.reminder_email = 1
   AND s.booking_date > NOW() 
   AND s.booking_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

This is my UPDATE Query thats give me an error

```
UPDATE ts_booking_bookings b
   set reminder_email = 0 
where id in (
SELECT b.id 
  FROM ts_booking_bookings b
  JOIN ts_booking_bookings_slots s
    ON b.id = s.booking_id
 WHERE b.reminder_email = 
   AND s.booking_date > NOW() 
   AND s.booking_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY))
```

Error

## 1093 - You can't specify target table 'ts_booking_bookings' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a slight modification to your current working join select syntax:

```
UPDATE ts_booking_bookings tsb
INNER JOIN ts_booking_bookings_slots tsbs
    ON tsb.id = tsbs.booking_id
SET
    tsb.reminder_email = 0
WHERE
    tsb.reminder_email = 1 AND
    tsbs.booking_date > NOW() AND
    tsbs.booking_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```